# REACT - Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-hooks, next.js

```
const [username, setUsername] = useState(null);

useEffect(async () => {
if (user) {
  const ref = doc(db, "users", `${user.uid}`);
  const snap = await getDoc(ref);
  if (snap.exists()) {
    console.log(snap.data() + "---data---");
    setUsername(snap.data().username);
  }
}
```

I can see the data in console. But in setUsername, its showing the error.
I am using firestore.

[image]

Comment: The surrounding code in the image does not seem to match your posted code. Can you post the actual code that produces the error ?

Comment: Most likely `snap.data()` returns a promise and you should use `await` before getting any value like `.username`. It works in the console most certainly because it gets evaluated by your browser, and gives you the result.

Comment: Please provide a [mre].